# difference of pid_t and int in C

Tags: c, types, process

what's the difference between pid_t datatype and int when getting process id?
I saw something like:

```
pid_t getpid(void);
```

but whats the difference between it and

```
int getpid(void);
```

Answer (score 8):

Quoting from the [libc manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Process-Identification.html):

> The pid_t data type is a signed integer type which is capable of
>   representing a process ID. In the GNU C Library, this is an int.

Answer (score 5):

data types that ends with "_t", are usually a defined type variable in C and C++ as an unwritten law.
according to that law, "pid_t" is a data type which is defined somewhere else but "int" a standard type; so to know the differences you need to know how "pid_t" is defined.

Comment: defined types are usually used to make the code more clear. using them also makes it more easier to change the code.